# Why does max function in sql return multiple values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I would like to display the player with the highest salary.

```
select  max(Salary) as highest_salary, p.[Last name]
from tbl_PlayersTable as p, tbl_team as t
where p.Team = t.TeamID
and TeamID = 1000
Group by p.[Last name]
```

The output is:

```
highest_salary  Last Name
   8000          Bosh
   7000          Wade
   6000          James
```

I just want to display (8000 Bosh since he is the player with highest salary).

Comment: Why are you grouping by last name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did't need `MAX` nor `GROUP BY`, just use `TOP 1` with `ORDER BY Salary DESC`. Something like this:

```
select TOP (1) Salary as highest_salary, p.[Last name]
from tbl_PlayersTable as p, tbl_team as t
where p.Team = t.TeamID
 and TeamID = 1000
ORDER BY Salary  DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you use `group by p.[Last name]` so that the query will get `max(Salary)` for each distinct `Last name` it found. So if you want to get the `max(Salary)` base on all of `Last name`, you must remove `group by`

Comment: it gives an error if i remove group by because i have a aggregate function in my select

Comment: if that's the case, use your current query as a `sub query` and wrap it by `select  max(Salary) as highest_salary, p.[Last name]
from`

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping values there (see Group By in the end) and so your max function calculates Max value per group. If you wand an absolute max value, remove the grouping.

Comment: it gives an error if i remove group by because i have a aggregate function in my select

Comment: See the top answer, it gives you a correct query, just replace LIMIT with SELECT TOP 1 as I mentioned there, this would be the syntax for sql server.

Comment: @ElDog if he remove group by than he can not get last name he wolud get only Max Value

Answer (score 1):

No need for `group by` or even `max`:

```
select  top 1 Salary
,       [Last name]
from    tbl_PlayersTable
where   TeamID = 1000
order by
        salary desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to take the top 1 value

```
  select TOP (1) Salary as maxsalary, p.[Last name]
   from tbl_PlayersTable as p 
   Inner join  tbl_team as t on  p.Team = t.TeamID
  where TeamID = 1000
  ORDER BY Salary  DESC
```